# How to define a certain number of nested for-loops (based on input length in R Shiny app)?

Tags: r, for-loop, input, shiny, nested-loops

Here is the context : I work on a R shiny web application. The user uploads a dataframe. Then he selects a certain *n* number of columns with a selectInput. This number of columns selected can vary from one to six.

Based on this number of columns, I would like to generate the appropriate number nested for-loops automatically. At that time, I use *if()* conditions by testing each possible number of columns selected.
I want to pass through each unique value of each column selected. That makes my code very long :

```
my_columns = input$colnames #The user selects column names

if(length(mycolumns) == 1){
 for(var1 in unique(mydataframe[,my_columns[1]])){
   ...
 }
}

if(length(mycolumns) == 2){
 for(var1 in unique(mydataframe[,my_columns[1]])){
    for(var2 in unique(mydataframe[,my_columns[2]])){
     ...
    }
  }
}

if(length(mycolumns) == 3){
 for(var1 in unique(mydataframe[,my_columns[1]])){
   for(var2 in unique(mydataframe[,my_columns[2]])){
     for(var3 in unique(mydataframe[,my_columns[3]])){
      ...
     }
   }
 }
}
```

and so on ...

Is there a solution to avoid this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am mistaken, but you seem to compute something that needs to cover all possible value combinations of the selected  columns.

R does not need nested for-loops for this case

```
my_columns <- data.frame(
  "A" = c(1,2,3),
  "B" = c(11,12,13),
  "C" = c(21,22,23))

# find all unique values per column
list_uniques <- lapply(seq_along(my_columns),
                       function(x){unique(my_columns[[x]])}
                       )

# find out all possible combinations of the given values
# the output is a dataframe
all_combinations <- expand.grid(list_uniques)

# Now you can iterate over the frame and do something with them

# example rowsums
rowSums(all_combinations) # vectorized functions like this are faster

# example custom function
apply(all_combinations,
              MARGIN = 1, # iterate rowwise
              # you can now use your own function
              # the input i is a row as a named vector
              FUN = function(i){paste(i,collapse = " and ")})
# This function will output:
# "1 and 11 and 21" "2 and 11 and 21" ....
```

Comment: Thank you, what you explained will be very usefull in the futur for other purposes but I don't think it will permit me to solve my curent problem... I want to apply filters to my data but my question was too broad

Comment: I do not understand what the body of your `for` loops is going to be. what should be the expected output of the most inner loop?

you are not able to use a function with a defined number of aguments: `myfun(var1,var2,var3)` will not work, when applied in only two for loops, as argument var3 is missing. 

Could you elaborate what you want to do within all those for loops?